# How would I build a rails model association for a belongs_to to get attributes from it's parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm working on a project that has two models: user and city.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

I'm saving the cities to the user as an integer (the primary key of the city). A user can only have one city and the cities table has pre-populated values:

```
id | name
1  | New York
2  | Chicago
3  | Boston
```

What kind of association would I need (and is it possible) to have so that I could call something like the below and get the city instead of the id?

```
user = User.find(id)
user.city
>> New York
```

Comment: `User.city` doesn't make any sense.. Why you want `User.city` should you give only one city name ?

Comment: I'd prefer to not have to do something where I find the city based off of the id saved. I can, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way

Comment: `User` class, which has a attribute `city`, which is a DB column. You can call attributes methods on the `User` object, but not on the `User` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an instance of a user, you would simply call `user.city.name` to get the name of the user's city:

```
user = User.find(1)
puts user.city.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing this has already been answered, I'd also add that if you have a lot of logic that requires this data that isn't contained within the model itself, it can make sense to add an instance method that calls the relationship's method. This allows for easier refactoring if the nature of that relationship changes.